# Минимальный код олимпиадных задач Java

Tags: java, алгоритм, олимпиада

Допустим, есть задачка про меньшее из трех чисел

> https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=757

Мой размер кода - 176 символов

```
import java.util.*;
class a{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(Math.min(s.nextLong()/2,Math.min(s.nextLong()/6,s.nextLong())));
    }
}
```

Я стараюсь максимально уменьшить код, но всегда **есть кто-то, кто напишет еще меньше кода**. Меня чертовски интересует, каким образом **они уменьшают код ЕЩЕ сильнее**, иногда это десятки символов. Если это касается алгоритмов, то я принимаю такой ответ, и буду стремиться всё дальше улучшать код) Но если же есть какие-то **ухищрения со стороны Java**, хотелось бы их очень сильно узнать. Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java

Comment: Да, старый добрый прогаммистский гольф :-)

Comment: @IR42 , Спасибо! Помог с arg и class public)

Answer (score 1):

олимпиадника на StackOverflow!

Джава - многословный язык.
Если посмотреть на частоту языков в самых коротких ответах, то это, чаще всего, C и C++.
Основной силой для сокращения кода на тих язывках является директива `#define` а так же использование непопулярных возможностей для комбинации операторов.

Пример решения задачи "Гвозди" от моего коллеги.

```
#include <fstream>
#define l >>
#define j abs((
#define k )*(
#define m )-(
#define n -y))-
main()
{
    std::fstream i("input.txt"), o("output.txt",2);
    int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,x,y,s=0;
    for(i l x;i l x l y l a l b l c l d l e l f l g l h;j a-e k d-f m c-e k b-f))+j a-g k f-h m e-g k b-h))-j a-x k d-y m c-x k b n j c-x k f-y m e-x k d n j e-x k h-y m g-x k f n j g-x k b-y m a-x k h n 0?0:s++);
    o<<s;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за информацию)  Но всё же, интересно как на Java всё делается в максимально кратком изложении. Отдельное уважение твоему коллеге за задачку, это что-то с чем-то лично для меня :)

Comment: чаще всего это какой-то Haskell или Clojure, но в таких языках есть одна проблема: там программисты седые в 25 лет. все всегда упирается в читаемость кода. для машины вообще все равно одна строка на Haskell  либо 1000 строк на бейсике, которые делают тоже самое. машина справится. и зачастую уменьшение количества кода действительно облегчает читаемость, но везде есть грань. за этой гранью получается эта самая одна строка кода на условном Haskell , для понимания которой нужен месяц.